# Bootstrap Fixed Header Responsive Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, bootstrap

Por favor necesito ayuda para dejar fijo el `header` de mi tabla con bootstrap.
Probé con varios ejemplos que circulan pero en ninguno consigo el resultado deseado.

Mi tabla contiene 11 columnas y esta dentro de un `div` responsive:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
<h4>TABLA</h4><br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12"><br>
<div class="table-responsive table-bordered">          
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Columna 1</th>
        <th>Columna 2</th>
        <th>Columna 3</th>
        <th>Columna 4</th>
        <th>Columna 5</th>
        <th>Columna 6</th>
        <th>Columna 7</th>
        <th>Columna 8</th>
        <th>Columna 9</th>
        <th>Columna 10</th>
        <th>Columna 11</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<!--ACA UN BUCLE FOR PHP RECORRIENDO UNA TABLA MySQL (cada registro de la BD es un registro de la tabla, en mi caso son unos 100-->

</tbody>
</table>
```

**¿Como puedo dejarlo fijo el encabezado?**

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Debes agregar mas código. ¿qué usaste para lograr la funcionalidad que mencionas? **edita tu pregunta**.

Comment: Hay un plugin que se llama **handsontable** quizá sea lo que busques, aclaro que es de paga, no lo he usado, pero lo he visto

Comment: No, handstone lo conozco y es un poco más de lo que necesito. Solo necesito que quede fijo el header de mi tabla porque tiene cientos de registros y 11 columnas entonces al bajar uno termina perdiendo la referencia de que es cada columna.

Vi varios ejemplos pero en todos mis columnas no entraban en la pantalla por lo que se situaban algunas por debajo del header..

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tienes un ejemplo de como hacerlo, deja fijo el encabezado y hace scroll del tbody.
https://codepen.io/yavuzselim/pen/LNYrBd

Editado: Añado aquí un resumen del código que hay en la página enlazada

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-3">First Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Last Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">E-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>    
      .........
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Css:

```
body{
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
.table-fixed{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  tbody{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    width: 100%;
    }
  thead,tbody,tr,td,th{
    display:block;
  }
  tbody{
    td{
      float:left;
    }
  }
  thead {
    tr{
      th{
        float:left;
       background-color: #f39c12;
       border-color:#e67e22;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Añadido Álvaro.

Answer (score 1):

Nada mas es agregar un "position: fixed;" a la clase de tu tabla, modificando tu codigo queda así:

```css
body{
  height: 1000px;
} // Height example  //

thead{
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
<h4>TABLA</h4><br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12"><br>
<div class="table-responsive table-bordered">          
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Columna 1</th>
        <th>Columna 2</th>
        <th>Columna 3</th>
        <th>Columna 4</th>
        <th>Columna 5</th>
        <th>Columna 6</th>
        <th>Columna 7</th>
        <th>Columna 8</th>
        <th>Columna 9</th>
        <th>Columna 10</th>
        <th>Columna 11</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<!--ACA UN BUCLE FOR PHP RECORRIENDO UNA TABLA MySQL (cada registro de la BD es un registro de la tabla, en mi caso son unos 100-->

</tbody>
</table>
```

**https://codepen.io/TheArgonaut/pen/aWxNPa**

Puedes, de igual forma, agregar algo mas en el css para posicionarlo correctamente, o un javascript que cambie automaticamente el posicionamiento del encabezado al bajar el scroll bar.